# Change header using sed or awk

Tags: sed, table

I have different file for which I would like to change the header.
Currently the tables are as follow:

```
MONTH GFDL.ESM2M_ECOMAG GFDL.ESM2M_HYPE
1 3546.21855483871 2345.11127781945
```

I would like to change the `.` by some `-` but just for the header. Therefore I would like the following output:

```
MONTH GFDL-ESM2M_ECOMAG GFDL-ESM2M_HYPE
1 3546.21855483871 2345.11127781945
```

So far I have try a `sed` command:

```
sed -i.bak "1,1s/./-/" file.txt
```

which just replace the `M` of `"MONTH"` by a `-`.
I have also tried an awk command:

```
awk '(NR==1){gsub(".","-", $0);}{print;}' file.txt > jony.txt
```

Which just replace the entire header by a succession of `-`

Comment: If this is related to your other question ... you can do it with a single awk invocation, no need to edit the files again just to replace some dots with dashes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed '1s/\./-/g' file.txt
```

should do it for you

---

**Why . ?**

Because the `.` has a special meaning in sed. It is used used match any characcter. You need to strip the special meaning by escaping it ie `\.`.

Comment: the `g` at the end is redundant but yes, it does the trick.

Comment: @MelBurslan : `g` is not redundant, the op need to replace all occurences of `.` in the header.

Comment: did you try the command without that `g`. I did and it works mighty fine...

Comment: @MelBurslan - it does _not_ work fine without `g` (regardless of your `sed` version). The only time `g` is redundant is when the pattern occurs only _once_ which isn't the case here (or in general)...

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` with `gsub()`:

```
awk 'NR==1 {gsub("\\.", "-", $0); quit};1' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt                                  
MONTH GFDL.ESM2M_ECOMAG GFDL.ESM2M_HYPE
1 3546.21855483871 2345.11127781945

$ awk 'NR==1 {gsub("\\.", "-", $0); quit};1' file.txt
MONTH GFDL-ESM2M_ECOMAG GFDL-ESM2M_HYPE
1 3546.21855483871 2345.11127781945
```

Comment: Using *gsub* for such task is overshot `awk -F. 'NR==1{$1=$1}1' OFS=-`